# Web Setup project not including some content files from ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, web-deployment-project, web-setup-project

I am making a WEB SETUP for my ASP.NET application. Below is my folder structure for content folder.

[image]

I have added a WEB SETUP project and have included the 'Primary output from Web' and 'Content files from Web'.

[image]

But when i right click on the 'Content files from Web' and select the 'Output' option I see the following

[image]

only my .svg font is added, the rest 4 files (.eot, .ttf, .woff and .otf) are not added. Even when I run the installer and after the setup is complete I still do not see these 4 files in the Content/font-awesome/font folder.

What should I do to add these to the installer as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Some font related files under your Content folder are probably not specified as "Content" files. You have to make Visual Studio understand that they are Content files. Content files are eventually copied to the compiled output directory when you execute your setup.exe file.

Just select your intended file(s) (using Ctrl-click if there are multiple files), right click choose Properties and from the Properties window, in front of "Build Action" choose "Content" option.

Now when you will Build and run your Setup.exe file, these files would be copied to the output directory.